# requests.HTTPError uncaught after a requests.get() 404 response

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch, python-requests

I'm having a slight problem with the requests library.

Say for example I have a statement like this in Python:

```
try:
   request = requests.get('google.com/admin') #Should return 404

except requests.HTTPError, e:
   print 'HTTP ERROR %s occured' % e.code
```

For some reason the exception is not being caught. I've checked the API documentation for requests but it's a bit slim. Is there anyone who has more experience with the library that might be able to help me out?

Comment: First thing first: when trying to catch unfamiliar exceptions, DO "raise" them and try to catch them and observe if/how it's possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interpreter is your friend:

```
import requests
requests.get('google.com/admin')
# MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'google.com/admin': No schema supplied
```

Also, `requests` exceptions:

```
import requests.exceptions
dir(requests.exceptions)
```

Also notice that by default `requests` doesn't raise exception if status is not `200`:

```
In [9]: requests.get('https://google.com/admin')
Out[9]: <Response [503]>
```

There is [raise_for_status()](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) method that does it:

```
In [10]: resp = requests.get('https://google.com/admin')

In [11]: resp
Out[11]: <Response [503]>

In [12]: resp.raise_for_status()
  ...
HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable
```

Comment: Do you know a website I can go to that will return a schema and force the HTTP error handler by any chance? And thank you, your answer was very helpful. I will be sure to use the interpreter from now on.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean. [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) is the part that specifies protocol (http, https, ftp, etc). So the error says that there is no scheme in `google.com/admin`, which should have been `https://google.com/admin`. You could override `requests` methods and check for missing scheme yourself and then add "http://" if it's missing, but it's not a good idea.

Comment: Alright, well I guess my problem is that even when I change my code to reflect https:// google.com/admin, purely as an example mind you, it will still return some random http response. I'm just curious as to why none of the responses are being caught whatsoever when I call requests.get('https:// google.com/admin'). Surely some kind of http error response will occur and it is not being caught =/

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the response. =)

Answer (score 2):

Running your code in python 2.7.5:

```
import requests

try:
  response = requests.get('google.com/admin') #Should return 404
except requests.HTTPError, e:
  print 'HTTP ERROR %s occured' % e.code
  print e
```

Results in:

`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 291, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema("Invalid URL %r: No schema supplied" % url)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'google.com/admin': No schema supplied`

To get your code to pick up this exception you need to add:

```
  except (requests.exceptions.MissingSchema) as e:
    print 'Missing schema occured. status'
    print e
```

Note also it is not a missing schema but a missing scheme.