# Python request stacks

Tags: python, json, request

Hi i try to request some json, all is ok, but sometimes request goes wrong, may be site stack or closing connection for me, cause i am requesting json every 15 min.

Code here:

```
def request_coins(config):
    coins = None
    print(str(datetime.now()) + ' - REQUESTING Coins')
    while coins is None:
        try:
            coins = (requests.get(url=str(config['UrlPath']['url']) + str(config['UrlPath']['userrates'])))
        except:
            print(str(datetime.now()) + " - Site didn't respond. Reconnecting in 10 sec")
        time.sleep(10)
     if coins is not None:
        coins = coins.json()['coins']
        print(str(datetime.now()) + ' - Coins received correctly')
return coins
```

Problems is that try - catch don't work in my case. Request stack in `print(str(datetime.now()) + ' - REQUESTING Coins')` and i don't recieve any exception and message to cmd

`print(str(datetime.now()) + " - Site didn't respond. Reconnecting in 10 sec")`

As I understood code stacks at `try: 
                coins = (requests.get(url=str(config['UrlPath']['url']) + 
                                    str(config['UrlPath']['userrates'])))`

and don't go even to `except`:

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: is your code structure correct for `if coins is not None:` ? Because python code is based on your tab.

Comment: yes, sorry miss tab when wrote here in original code all is ok

Comment: I guess your `requests.get` is just busy, without raising an error... So you should look into `requests` combined with `try - except`. Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511337/correct-way-to-try-except-using-python-requests-module)? Maybe the second part of the accepted answer with the `Response.raise_for_status` could be helpful?

Comment: Sorry for double-posting, but I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206062/requests-httperror-uncaught-after-a-requests-get-404-response/16206247#16206247), where @gatto writes "Also notice that by default `requests` doesn't raise exception if status is not 200". You need the `(whatever).raise_for_status()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add `timeout` to get request

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail to make your answer more useful.